# Radio button focus on DocuSign templates

Tags: docusignapi

We have are getting a strange behavior with the radio groups in our templates. Each of the radio groups is required, however, when a radio button from a group is selected, the next radio button (not the next group) gets focus. This will confuse our users as they will think they have to click each radio. Moreover, it would be helpful if an entire group could have focus as opposed to individual radios.

Is there a way to give the group focus as opposed to the individual radio?

Answer (score 1):

The manner in which Radio Buttons (or any other type of input element) get focus in the Signing Session UI is not configurable via the API, nor is it configurable via the DocuSign web console.

Comment: Meaning there is no way to have a group get focus?

Comment: Actually, this can be changed in Preferences->Account Administration->Features. By setting "signing auto-navigation rule" to "page only" one is able to shut off the auto focusing of the next element.

Answer (score 0):

we can change this option from Docusign settings.
Preferences->Account Administration->Features->signing auto-navigation rule-> Navigate Blank Required Fields

This will move focus to next field when a radio button is selected from Radio group.